# Remove controls from embedded video

Tags: html, embed, flv

I am looking to have flv videos displayed on my site, without any controls, and playing in a loop. So far I've succeeded with JWPlayer, however I do not wish to pay for a license, nor do I want to have their watermark on my videos. (They are meant to be seen as banner-type videos, hence my need to remove the controls)

I've also been able to get it right with this:

```
<embed src ="http://www.bsnwebsites.com/videos/player/player.swf?file=http://www.bsnwebsites.com/videos/blueflame.flv" width="220" height="100" allowfullscreen="true" align="left"/>
```

But then I can't seem to find the right parameter to remove the controls. I've googled it, to no avail. Any way this can be done?

Thank you

Comment: yes, I have done this and have an example at home if you still need the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add

```
hidden="true"
```

This will hide your player....you need to use `<object>` tag. 
Please [read the article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/byebyeembed) for type of video you need to embed in ur page